# Failed to install PATCH_SUPEE-7616_CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2016-01-20-03-08-56.sh for Magento 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, security, patches

I am trying to install patch SUPEE-7616 but it's failed. I am getting error:
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 544.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 579.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 612.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 624.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 659.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 692.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 742.
Hunk #8 FAILED at 781.
Hunk #9 FAILED at 834.
Hunk #10 FAILED at 857.
Hunk #11 FAILED at 1423.
11 out of 11 hunks FAILED

Usps.php file is original,  without any updates. And SUPEE-7405 was installed successfully. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you applied PATCH_SUPEE-6237 and PATCH_SUPEE-4334 patches before applying latest patch?

Comment: PATCH_SUPEE-6237 - already installed, but PATCH_SUPEE-4334 - no.

Comment: When I am trying to install SUPEE-4334, getting new errors:
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 340.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 533.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 547.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 573.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 588.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 595.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 621.
Hunk #8 succeeded at 775 with fuzz 2 (offset 57 lines).
Hunk #9 FAILED at 737.
Hunk #10 FAILED at 745.
9 out of 10 hunks FAILED

Comment: SUPEE-4334 should be installed before SUPEE-6237

Comment: But it wasn't. And what now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep backup of your `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php` file and replace it with the default *Usps.php* file shipped with Magento 1.8.0.0.

Now apply the patches in the following order.

1. SUPEE-4291/4334
2. SUPEE-6237
3. SUPEE-7616

Try with above mentioned and see if it helps you.

Also refer following link https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But now when installing SUPEE-4291/4334 have this error:  
hecking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully. checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 340.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 533.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 547.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 573.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 588.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 595.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 621.
Hunk #8 succeeded at 775 with fuzz 2 (offset 57 lines).
Hunk #9 FAILED at 737.
Hunk #10 FAILED at 745.
9 out of 10 hunks FAILED
And this is with default Usps.php